# How to get data and create an array from an object when keys are same in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This is the scenario I am talking about:

```
let obj = {
      id: "kjhgfr^&*()(*UY",
      id: "kjhgfr^OIJHB",
      id: "kjhgfr^)(*&^%Y",
      id: "DFGHI(*&YTRDTYHKI*",
      id: ")(IUHGVYUJKO))(*UY",
      id: "VGYUKO(*UYH",
      id: "BHYUIOP)(*&^T%",
      id: "0987654567890",
      id: "5678909876543",
    };
```

I want to create an array with ids like this.

```
[
  "5678909876543",
  "0987654567890",
  "VGYUKO(*UYH",
  "kjhgfr^&*()(*UY",
  "VGYUKO(*UYH",
];
```

Comment: What do you mean "Key are the same"?

Comment: I think you cannot have duplicate keys. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think your obj is invalid

Comment: obj needs to have unique keys, it can't have duplicate keys

Comment: Your object will be `{id: "5678909876543"}`, so... no duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2):

Your object is incorrect.

Possible it is the same as:
[Javascript object literal - possible to add duplicate keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790146/javascript-object-literal-possible-to-add-duplicate-keys)

As a result, it will be override to get the last value.

```js
let obj ={id:"kjhgfr^&*()(*UY",id:"kjhgfr^OIJHB",id:"kjhgfr^)(*&^%Y",id:"DFGHI(*&YTRDTYHKI*",id:")(IUHGVYUJKO))(*UY",id:"VGYUKO(*UYH",id:"BHYUIOP)(*&^T%",id:"0987654567890",id:"5678909876543",};

console.log(obj);
// { "id": "5678909876543"}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have duplicate keys. Each identical key will overwrite the previously defined value.

You could try this instead (assuming you have control over the input):

```
let obj = {
      id: ["kjhgfr^&*()(*UY",
      "kjhgfr^OIJHB",
      "kjhgfr^)(*&^%Y",
      "DFGHI(*&YTRDTYHKI*",
      ")(IUHGVYUJKO))(*UY",
      "VGYUKO(*UYH",
      "BHYUIOP)(*&^T%",
      "0987654567890",
      "5678909876543"]
    };
```

This is similar to the following question: [Read and loop through an object with non-unique key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484034/read-and-loop-through-an-object-with-non-unique-key-value-pairs)